# touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event not getting fired every time

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing

I am using several views all the views are subviews for the scrollview, on a particular view I am drawing something like free draw lines using the `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event,touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`,`- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` methods.

Question: sometimes when I draw a curve line very fast, the `touchesMoved:` method is not getting fired. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Guess: scrollView may have touches delay, is it causing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue due to scroll View's delaysContentTouches , set this to NO and try the same...

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply i will try it.